# Repeat Regex pattern with line feed and line continuations

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do you get a string that has line feeds (vbNewLine, vblf, vbcrlf, etc) and line continuations. The following only seems to be retrieving the "First line of text.".

```
Dim rx As Regex
Dim var1 As String = "First line of text. " & vbNewLine & _
                     "Second line of text. " & vbNewLine & _
                     "Third line of text."

rx = New Regex(".*[\n\r]")
Dim search As String = rx.Match(var1).Value
```

Expected result: search = "First line of text. Second line of text. Third line of text."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For matching multiline patterns with a regex you must use the singleline option. It modifies the dot behavior so that it captures every character, newlines included.

```
rx = New Regex("(?s).*")
```

Link to msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline).

Comment: This did the trick. I had to adjust it to rx = New Regex("(?s).*"). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look At the Regexoption 'RegexOptions.MultiLine'. it should be the second parameter of your Regex object Like this:

```
rx = New Regex(".*[\n\r]", RegexOptions.MultiLine)
```

I think that will do the trick.
If it is only to replace the Line feeds with spaces, The function String.Replace will suffice too.

Answer (score 0):

To get more than just the first match, please use `rx.Matches(var1)`. After this you can iterate over the collection.

Note however that your regex has an error: the last line will not be matched due to not being followed by a newline. An easy fix would be:

```
rx = new Regex("\n");
var matches = rx.Split(var1);
//iterate collection
```

note code is in c# due to tag.